# Colander pronunciation

Tags: pronunciation

My mother always pronounced colander "culander" and corrected me if I pronounced otherwise. No change in emphasis, just the second letter sound. Does anyone else pronounce it thus, or is our family some kind of exception?

Comment: Where's your mom from?

Comment: @TinfoilHat I think it's mostly a British English influence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not just you. Pronunciations that sound like "cullender" are extant in English.

The [Oxford English Dictionary](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/36075) lists /ˈkələndər/ as well as /ˈkɑləndər/ as American pronunciations. The British pronunciation listed is /ˈkʌləndə/. The vowels run the range of what I would expect:

- /ɑ/ is the same vowel sound as in American [hot], and is a common way to pronounce [o] vowels.
- /ə/ is a mid-central vowel, as heard in the second [a] in [arena]. Americans sometimes pronounce [u] vowels that way (e.g., [cut] or [shut]) as well as other vowels (like the [o] in [some] or [company]).
- /ʌ/ is how British folk would likely pronounce [u] in [cut] or [shut] as well as [o] in [some] and [company]. As with American English, I would expect substantial variation in the vowel used.

Why these different vowels? Historically, colander was spelled with both a [col-] and [cul-] spelling from the 1500s onward. While *colander* is the most common spelling, some dictionaries also list *cullender* as a variant form: [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/cullender), [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cullender), and (as an "archaic variant") [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cullender). The spelling may reflect some crossover in pronunciation between /ɑ/ or /ʌ/ or /ə/.

Answer (score 2):

*Americn Heritge Dictionary* shows pronunciation:
[image]

So, it seems, some others do agree with your mother.

Answer (score 2):

It's a regional matter. In UK many people pronounce the '**o**' as you say, as given by [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/colander).

There are other words too, such as **worry**. Hear the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/worry) pronunciation.

It's regional *within* the UK too. In recent years I have noticed the BBC News channels pronouncing such words with the short '**o**' sound.

Some more words are front, some, love, glove, monkey, honey, oven, won and son.
Vowels in particular have quite variable pronunciation amongst English speakers.

Comment: What relevance do the pronunciations of the other words you list have to the pronunciation of *colander*?

Comment: @RosieF they are examples of other words where the '**o**' is not pronounced the way a language learner might expect. For example I have never heard an English speaker pronounce 'love' any way except 'luv'. Also, compare 'monkey' with 'donkey'.

Comment: I see that, but I don't see how this makes your case regarding *colander*. After all, the pronunciations of such words don't imply that the o in *donkey* is pronounced the same way (to use your example from your comment), so why should they have any bearing on *colander*?

Comment: @RosieF the dictionary audio clip makes the case. From there, I point out that it isn't at all unusual – and perhaps murraybiscuit pronounces some of those words with a 'u' sound. The monkey / donkey example is to show there is no consistency to pronunciation from the spelling.